# Why do I get the error 'Can't locate Plack/Handler/Apache2.pm in @INC' when I install Request Tracker on CentOS 7?

Tags: apache, perl, http, rt

I am installing [Request Tracker](https://www.bestpractical.com/rt/) on my CentOS 7 machine. When I start the httpd server, I get the following error:

> Can't locate Plack/Handler/Apache2.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd) at /etc/httpd/conf.d/rt.conf line 17.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted

Any idea on why I am getting this error?

Comment: Did you successfully run 'make testdeps' during installation? I should track down all of the dependencies for you, and 'make fixdeps' can install them.

Comment: yes I did. And it was successful.

Comment: Hmm, that can could suggest that the perl libraries you used when running the install are different than the those used by the web server user. This could be a permissions mismatch or potentially pointing at a different perl if there are multiple on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plack::Handler::Apache2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Handler::Apache2) isn't part of the standard Perl installation. You need to install it separately. It's part of the [Plack](https://metacpan.org/release/Plack) distribution, so one easy way to install it is with:

```
$ sudo yum install perl-Plack
```

Comment: thanks it helped me solve the plack handler issue but again following error showed up

Can't locate UNIVERSAL/require.pm in @INC..............

Comment: If you have a new question, then please ask it as a new question.

Comment: @DuongNguyen It does still work. If you're having a problem with it, then why not post a question explaining your situation?